# Экранирование implode

Tags: экранирование, php, база-данных

Есть массив со столбцами в бд и значения строки:

```
array( "id", "uniq_id", "tm", "category", "price", "text", "size", "image", "author" ),

array( 1, 1, "tm", "category", 123, "text", 6, "imagepath", "author" )
```

Я преобразую в строку через implode,
вывожу строку и вижу такую штуку:

```
string(145) "INSERT INTO jshop_magazine ( id,uniq_id,tm,category,price,text,size,image,author ) VALUES ( 1, 1, tm, category, 123, text, 6, imagepath, author )"
```

Текст без кавычек, как исправить? Пробовал делать, как [здесь](http://forum.ru-board.com/topic.cgi?forum=31&topic=16056).

Получилось

```
string(180) "INSERT INTO jshop_magazine ( id,uniq_id,tm,category,price,text,size,image,author ) VALUES ( "1\", \"1\", \"tm\", \"category\", \"123\", \"text\", \"6\", \"imagepath\", \"author\" )"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы видите текст без кавычек, так как кавычки при инициализации массива, выступают в качестве синтаксиса. Если вы действительно хотите кавычки, то можно сделать следующее: 
   `array('"id"', '"uniq_id"', '"tm"', '"category"', '"price"', '"text"', '"size"', '"image"', '"author"' );`
2. При объединении для получения кавычек можно использовать следующий способ:
   `$columns = array( "id", "uniq_id", "tm", "category", "price", "text", "size", "image", "author");
   $join = implode('", "', $columns);
   $result = '"' . $join . '"';`

Answer (score 0):

Что бы не запутаться в кавчках попробуйте так

```
    $xml_ids=[
      11111,
     033333,
     444444,
       5555555
       ];

    $xml_ids = (function()use($xml_ids) {
                foreach ($xml_ids as &$value) {
                    $value = "'{$value}'";
                }
                return $xml_ids;
            })();

    $xml_ids = rtrim(implode(',', $xml_ids), ',');

    $query="DELETE FROM {$table_name} WHERE XML_ID NOT IN({$xml_ids})";
```

По ссылке просто расширенная версия и от куда смотрел и сам брал
https://coderun.ru/prostye-otvety/php-rezultat-implode-v-kavychki-dlya-zaprosa-v-mysql/